# simple Forge 3-legged Oauth with node.js

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am new to Forge and using node.js - I am having some difficulty getting a simple 3-legged Oauth process to work.

This is how far I have got below. It gives me the error "Cannot GET /api/forge/oauth/callback"

I have checked that my callback url matches what is in the Forge App.

Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is, getting the shared link for a newly created file in Fusion teams, or at least opening the browser to the file overview page.

Would anybody be able to help with this?

```
var express = require('express');
var ForgeSDK = require('forge-apis');
const { stringify } = require('node:querystring');
var opn = require('opn'); 

// Set up Express web server
var app = express();

// Set the Forge Variables
var FORGE_CLIENT_ID = 'client-id', FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET = 'client-secret', REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/forge/oauth/callback';

// This is for web server to start listening to port 3000
app.set('port', 3000);
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

// Initialize the 3-legged OAuth2 client, set specific scopes and optionally set the `autoRefresh` parameter to true
// if you want the token to auto refresh
var autoRefresh = true;
var oAuth2ThreeLegged = new ForgeSDK.AuthClientThreeLegged(FORGE_CLIENT_ID, FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL, [
    'data:read',
    'data:write'
], autoRefresh);

// Generate a URL page that asks for permissions for the specified scopes.
var AuthURL = oAuth2ThreeLegged.generateAuthUrl();
    console.log(AuthURL)

opn('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<<client-id>>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/api/forge/oauth/callback&scope=data:read+data:write&state=undefined', {app: 'chrome'})
```

Answer (score 0):

where is the callback API in your code?

BTW 3-Legged oauth is implemented here in nodejs, you can use it as reference:
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/oauth/3legged/nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is that you have a callback which you need to wait for. I also added a function to refresh the token automatically:

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as open from 'open';
const os = require("os");
var ForgeSDK = require('forge-apis');
const fs = require("fs");
import { dirname } from 'path';
//thats the function: I wrapped in a class together with settings. you need also a function to save the credentials as json:
async _3leggedOff(autoRefresh = true, options?) {
    // Initialize the 3-legged OAuth2 client, set specific scopes and optionally set the `autoRefresh` parameter to true
        var oAuth2ThreeLegged = new ForgeSDK.AuthClientThreeLegged(this._settings.clientId, this._settings.clientSecret, this._settings.callback, this.settings.opts.scope.split(' '), autoRefresh);
        //check file exists when autorefresh is enabled
        if (autoRefresh && fs.existsSync(this._settings.path_credentials)) {
            console.debug("try to read credentials from " + this._settings.path_credentials)
            let data = await fs.readFileSync(this._settings.path_credentials, 'utf8');
            data = await JSON.parse(data);
            console.debug(this._settings.path_credentials + ":" + JSON.stringify(data))
            try {
                let res = await oAuth2ThreeLegged.refreshToken(data, this.settings.opts.scope.split(' '));
                console.log("Refreshed the token successful")
                this.credentials_save(res);
                return true

            }
            catch (err) {
                console.error(err)
            }

        }
        // Generate a URL page that asks for permissions for the specified scopes.
        const url = oAuth2ThreeLegged.generateAuthUrl()
        console.debug("url:", url);

        //configure and start the server to listen to the callback
        const app = express();
        let resolve;
        const p = new Promise((_resolve) => {
            resolve = _resolve;
        });
        //this assumes the callback url is localhost/oauth
        app.get('/oauth', function (req, res) {
            resolve(req.query.code);
            res.end('');
        });
        const server = await app.listen(this._settings.PORT);
        console.debug("Started localhost", this._settings.PORT, "waiting for callback ", this._settings.callback);

        //open the browser to login
        open(url);

        // Wait for the first auth code on the port of the localhost
        const returned_code = await p;
        //close the server because else cli would never exit
        await server.close();
        console.debug("retured:", returned_code)

        //get the token for the credentials
        oAuth2ThreeLegged.getToken(returned_code).then(function (credentials) {
            // The `credentials` object contains an `access_token` and an optional `refresh_token` that you can use to call the endpoints.
            this.credentials_save(credentials);
            return true
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
}
```